# What are these Linux system calls to get some information of a specified process

Tags: linux, process, system, call

I'm writing a system call in Linux to get the data of a a specified process.

such as `process's start time` , `the numbers of siblings of the process`

Although I found there is a `task_struct` which contains a lot of data I need such as `start_time`

or I could call 
`getpid()` 
to get the process ID,

I still don't know exactly how to get a specified process's start_time, numbers of siblings or any other information by a given process ID.

Comment: `getpid()` is a system call, so it can't be called on kernel space.

Comment: so, would you please tell me what I should do ?

Comment: What have you tried this far? You might get better/more answers if you show some effort in terms of producing actual code which could then be commented in answers.